# MYSQL Database ID's

Tags: mysql, database

When someone registers on my site they get variables in 3 different tables.

However, due to unknown reasons, the ID's for some tables are more pushed up than others.

So someone will register and get these ID's

Table 1 - ID 12
Table 2 - ID 15
Table 3 - ID 13

I utilise these ID's being the same for various table joins, every user that signs up I have to manually go in and change the ID's!

I'm not sure what to do, it's really tedious. Should I just wipe the databases and restart?

Comment: hmm, maybe you can consider to rethink your db. Register an user in an user table with a id as PK (Primary Key). Use that PK as FK (Foreign Key) in other tables to have a reference between a variable in a table 1/2/3 with an user X.

Comment: @KarelG That's what I do but the ID's are out of order

Comment: What do you mean they are out of order.  How can that be if you have primary key/ foreign key relationships?

Comment: You should redesign your database and restart.  Doing what you are trying to do is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Linger I manually change the key. Someone will register and the 3 tables don't have the same ID's for that user, so I look at the user's user ID and change the other tables accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like all three of your tables are set to auto-increment, and you are trying to imply a foreign-key relationship between them using their primary keys. This can work in the short-term, but if records are manually inserted, or if you have a scenario where not all three tables have data inserted, it will throw things off. You can reset the auto increment value to whatever you'd like, but this is only a temporary fix.

If this is the case, you should identify which of these is really the "master" table in relation to the others. Then ask yourself, is it really necessary to split this data into three tables, when in fact it all relates 1:1? And finally, if it is necessary to do so, then a best-practice you should consider would be to declare separate fields in the child tables and define these as having explicit foreign-key relationships to the master table.

I've only just registered so I can't comment, but it would be helpful if you could show the "create table" SQL statements.

Comment: Much better idea than the currently accepted (and wrong) answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you know what you are doing and really want it to work this way. Then you can set the Auto Increment value to a specific number, like this `ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100`.

If you don't really know what you are doing. You better read more about using databases, primary keys, relationship tables and more.

Comment: That's perfect, I'll do both :)

Comment: How on earth does this help?  The next ID's will just be 112, 115, 113.  This will do nothing to keep the three tables in sync.

Comment: @Gerrat What are you talking about? The proposed command will set auto_increment, not increase it. The next ID's will be 100, 100, 100. You're right about that this won't *keep* the tables in sync, that's why I made sure it's a solution just in case he absolutely knows what he's doing.